# What explains the feeling of 'yuck...'?

Tags: word-request

I'm searching for a word that explains 'yuck' expression of mine. I mean it's not that there is fear. Nor do I dislike...but it's something like 'yuck!'

For example, if I see a worm, I get irritated. I am not scared of it but it's something like I may *throw up.*

Disgusting is pretty close but not sure if there's any better word to describe my feeling.

It happens when I see a worm, or filthy place, or a cockroach...and so on.

Question is: I'm not *afraid* of worms, but I just feel _________.

Comment: How about nauseated.

Comment: There is a sticker called "Mister Yuck" which people place on toxic home cleaning products that are typically stored under the kitchen sink here in the US.  It shows a caricature of a face that looks as if it has just eaten something foul and disgusting. The sticker is supposed to discourage toddlers from getting the idea that what is inside these containers is tasty. They should find the idea of tasting it revolting. You feel **revolted** when you see worms.

Comment: What makes you think ***disgusted*** isn't the "best" word for your context?

Comment: @fumblefingers I have two different words in my mother and national tongues for this. I need another word because disgusting is also related to annoying and anger.

Comment: But English is *not* your mother tongue! Just because what you think of as the equivalent of ***disgusting*** in your language has unwanted associations doesn't mean you should extend that "problem" to the English term itself.

Comment: How about [*icky*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/icky): "3. 
very distasteful; disgusting"?

Answer (score 3):

[**to gross someone out**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gross-out):

> If something grosses you out, it makes you feel disgusted.

The following is your example slightly reworked:

> It's not that I'm afraid of worms or anything like that, it's just that all creepy-crawly things really **gross me out**.

Comment: We should point out that if great-grandma or great-grandpa were to say **it grosses me out**, it would sound a little funny.  It is the teen slang of the 1970s.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, Thanks for that valuable piece of information, but I didn't know that it was a relatively new expression.

Comment: "grossed out" would fill in the blank.

Comment: *gross me out* is really close! +1 already!

Answer (score 1):

Question is: I'm not afraid of worms, but I just feel _________.

"disgusted"

Answer (score 1):

- to feel yucky is to feel unwell (sick in AmE, ill in BrE)
- makes me feel yucky= I guess disgust could make someone feel unwell.

In which case, yucky would work for you.

"I felt yucky after eating all that cake."

: repugnant, distasteful; also : unpleasant, disagreeable felt yucky a yucky chore

[feel yucky in Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yucky)

Answer (score 0):

If you literally feel like you "may throw up", you feel "nauseous".

([James](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/76234) posted a similar comment.)